# How to remove unwanted messages in debug output window - Xamarin on visual studio

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-debugging

I need the Xamarin expert help. I am struggling to disable the unwanted noise message in Output windows while debugging the Xamarin program since last 2 days. I am deploying my application on Samsung Tablet in debug mode. I am not able to read my message as output windows have been flooded with noise message as below.

It was working perfectly couple of days back then suddenly all these message appear.

How to disable it?

Example:

```
12-04 22:37:01.740 I/System.out( 6464): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-04 22:37:01.740 I/System.out( 6464): KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
12-04 22:37:01.750 I/System.out( 6464): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-04 22:37:01.750 I/System.out( 6464): KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
12-04 22:37:01.770 I/System.out( 6464): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-04 22:37:01.770 I/System.out( 6464): KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
12-04 22:37:01.810 D/Mono    ( 6464): GC_BRIDGE waiting for bridge processing to finish
12-04 22:37:01.860 I/art     ( 6464): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 30396(1325KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(378KB) LOS objects, 30% free, 37MB/53MB, paused 610us total 46.997ms
12-04 22:37:01.870 D/Mono    ( 6464): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 988 objects 1004 opaque 57 colors 988 colors-bridged 988 colors-visible 988 xref 11 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.27ms tarjan 1.10ms scc-setup 0.67ms gather-xref 0.06ms xref-setup 0.03ms cleanup 0.37ms
12-04 22:37:01.870 D/Mono    ( 6464): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 62.26ms
12-04 22:37:01.870 D/Mono    ( 6464): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 30.52ms, stw 31.34ms promoted 1332K major size: 4944K in use: 4148K los size: 1024K in use: 349K
12-04 22:37:01.870 I/System.out( 6464): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-04 22:37:01.880 I/System.out( 6464): KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
12-04 22:37:01.890 I/System.out( 6464): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-04 22:37:01.890 I/System.out( 6464): KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
12-04 22:37:01.900 I/System.out( 6464): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-04 22:37:01.900 I/System.out( 6464): KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
12-04 22:37:01.920 I/System.out( 6464): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-04 22:37:01.920 I/System.out( 6464): KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
12-04 22:36:42.351 V/MediaPlayer( 6464): callback application
12-04 22:36:42.351 V/MediaPlayer( 6464): back from callback
12-04 22:36:42.361 V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 6464): getCurrentPosition: 5237 (msec)
12-04 22:36:42.361 V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 6464): seekTo: 0(msec)
12-04 22:36:42.361 V/MediaPlayer( 6464): seekTo 0
12-04 22:36:42.371 V/MediaPlayer( 6464): message received msg=7, ext1=0, ext2=0
12-04 22:36:42.731 V/MediaPlayer( 6464): unrecognized message: (7, 0, 0)
12-04 22:36:42.731 V/MediaPlayer( 6464): callback application
12-04 22:36:42.731 V/MediaPlayer( 6464): back from callback
12-04 22:36:42.741 V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 6464): isPlaying: 0
12-04 22:36:42.751 V/MediaPlayer-JNI( 6464): isPlaying: 0
12-04 22:37:01.970 I/System.out( 6464): KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
12-04 22:37:01.980 I/System.out( 6464): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-04 22:37:01.980 I/System.out( 6464): KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
12-04 22:37:02.000 I/System.out( 6464): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-04 22:37:02.000 I/System.out( 6464): KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
12-04 22:37:02.010 I/System.out( 6464): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-04 22:37:02.010 I/System.out( 6464): KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
12-04 22:37:02.030 I/System.out( 6464): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
12-04 22:37:02.030 I/System.out( 6464): KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Tools->Options->Xamarin->Android->Output Verbosity

Comment: HI I have update the Output verbosity to "Quiet" then still noise messages are flooding.

Comment: Any suggestion please

Answer (score 2):

These messages can very often overload the Output window. Many of them are very helpful, many not at all. But if you want to see only your custom messages, you need to filter them out.

I tried `Tools | Options | Debugging | General > Redirect all Output Window text to the Immediate Window` , but it didn't redirect the messages in a Xamarin Forms project. I used an external device, maybe with an mobile emulator it could work.

You can try these plugins/tools:

- [VSColorOutput](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MikeWard-AnnArbor.VSColorOutput) - add a color to your messages. For example if you start every message with a keyword (app name or some other keyword like "+++") and then add a pattern to this keyword, it will change the color of the message in the output window.
- [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/sk-sk/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) - this tool will intercept/catch your Debug.Write messages, but only from your local system. Personally I don't know how it will react to an external device such a mobile phone.
- [Filter Debug Window](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nertilpoci.FilterDebugWindow) - ads a filter to the debug window.

Comment: I accomplished this using the filter debug window plugin as per this answer, which worked well

Answer (score 1):

You can remove other output messages by doing the following steps:

- Add something in your logged messages to differentiate between yours and the other ones that you don't care about:

```
Console.WriteLine("[App] This is my message");
Console.WriteLine("[App] Another message from me");
```

- Open the *Device Log* window

[image]

- Type in the search field to find your messages only:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to filter Visual Studio output too, and so eventually I decided to write an extension to do it. If you're interested, you can check it out at [niahtextfilter.com](https://www.niahtextfilter.com).

Here's an idea of what it does (this shows it filtering on a keyword, but you can also inverse filter on a keyword which is what the OP wants):

[image: Niah Text Filter filtering debug output]